# How do I get my JUnit tests in Eclipse working again?

Tags: eclipse, junit, junit4, eclipse-kepler

I’m using Eclipse Kepler on Mac 10.9.5 (Java 8).  Fairly recently, running JUnit tests through Eclipse stopped working.  That is, I right click on my JUnit class name in the main editor window, select “Run As” and then “JUnit Test”, and notice in the lower right, there is a status message saying “Launching MYTest … 37%”, but when that message disappears, nothing else happens.  Nothing appears in the JUnit perspective and no tests are run.

Short of completely uninstalling and re-installing Eclipse, what can I do to troubleshoot this issue and get JUnit working again?  This happens with any test I try and run.

Comment: tried a restart using -clean parameter ? and then restart normal and try test run again...

Comment: Are you talking about -clean in the eclipse.ini file?

Comment: Yes, but it is better to restart it with -clean in command prompt. You will need to run it once, then restart without -clean. `eclipse.exe -clean` and then restart normal without the -clean param.